# PHP Autoformat Paragraph tags

Tags: php, html, autoformatting

This is a fairly basic question however I've only ever managed to find three answers. I want to autoparagraph unformatted content that may or may not contain other html elements. The two good to go functions are the wordpress [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop), [HTMLPurifier AutoFormat.AutoParagraph](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#AutoFormat.AutoParagraph) and lastly some random [addParagraphsNew](http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=105291#p562847). However the first is incompatible with my applications license, the second doesn't add line breaks within the paragraph tags and the third is flakey.

Does anyone know on a commercially suitable licensed script that allows html content that has line breaks and double line breaks to be converted into `<br />` and `<p>` tags?

I believe the HTMLPurifier option is probably the best way to go my hacking into the AutoFormat.AutoParagraph plugin to get it to add line breaks but I was hoping was something slightly easier. Lazy I know.

Comment: All you want to do is replace single line breaks with <br /> and double line breaks with <p> ? Isn't that easy?

Comment: It would be if you assume there is no html. Once you have html in the mix you can end up with broken tags if you start replacing new lines without accounting for them.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide some examples of content that isn't being processed correctly

Answer (score 5):

well you could hack it yourself (if I understand what you need correctly)

```
$text = "hello, I am text

and this is another paragraph, please do some cool
stuff with this (this is after a  line break)

last apragrahp...";

$text = str_replace("\r\n","\n",$text);

$paragraphs = preg_split("/[\n]{2,}/",$text);
foreach ($paragraphs as $key => $p) {
    $paragraphs[$key] = "<p>".str_replace("\n","<br />",$paragraphs[$key])."</p>";
}

$text = implode("", $paragraphs);

echo $text;
```

That will actually output this:

```
<p>hello, I am text</p><p>and this is another paragraph, please do some cool<br />stuff with this (this is after a  line break)</p><p>last apragrahp...</p>
```

Notice how it's missing all the newlines etc. now...

Comment: this doesn't take into account html, which may or may not exist. If a <p> tag gets closed around a <li> or in an <a> then the resultant html will be broken.

Comment: ahh sorry.. I misread this line: that may or may not contain other html elements - I thought you said that it may not contain other elements.. ok.. so I would go with the wordpress function.. I'll delete this answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JavaScript solution that will add paragraph tags to lines. It will ignore lines that are empty, headers, images, lists and within code blocks.

```js
function Add_paragraph_tags(input)
{
    console.log('Adding paragraph tags');
    var lines = input.split("\n");
    line_is_inside_code_block = false;
    line_is_inside_pre_block = false;
    line_is_inside_table = false;
    line_is_inside_comment = false;
    line_is_inside_video = false;
    line_is_inside_css_block = false;

    lines.forEach
    (
            function(line, index)
            {
                    lines[index] = lines[index].replace(/\<h[1-9]\>\<\/h[1-9]\>/,''); //remove instances of <h2></h3>
                    lines[index] = lines[index].replace(/\<(h[1-9]\>)(.*)\<\/h[1-9]\>/,'<$1$2</$1');
                    if(
                            line==''
                            || /^[ |\t]*<h/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<a/.test(line)
                            //|| /^[ |\t]*<p/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<br/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<img/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<\/?div/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<pre/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<code/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<table/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<iframe/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<figure/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<figcaption/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<li>/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<ol>/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<\/ol>/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<ul>/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<\/ul>/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<blockquote><p>/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<video/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<style/.test(line)
                            || /^[ |\t]*<!--/.test(line)
                            || line_is_inside_code_block
                            || line_is_inside_pre_block
                            || line_is_inside_table
                            || line_is_inside_comment
                            || line_is_inside_video
                            || line_is_inside_css_block
                    )
                    {
                            //do nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            lines[index] = '<p>' + line + '</p>';
                            lines[index] = lines[index].replace('<p><blockquote>','<blockquote><p>');
                            lines[index] = lines[index].replace('</blockquote></p>','</p></blockquote>');
                            lines[index] = lines[index].replace(/(\<p\>)+/,'<p>'); //elimlnate multiple p tags
                            lines[index] = lines[index].replace(/(\<\/p\>)+/,'</p>'); //elimlnate multiple closing p tags
                            lines[index] = lines[index].replace(/\<p\>\<\/p\>/,''); //elimlnate <p></p>
                    }

                    /*if(lines[index+1].startsWith('<br'))
                    {
                            lines[index] = lines[index].replace(/\<\/p\>)/,'');
                    }*/

                    if(line.endsWith('</code>'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_code_block = false;
                    }
                    else if(line.endsWith('</pre>'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_pre_block = false;
                    }
                    else if(line.endsWith('</table>'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_table = false;
                    }
                    else if(line.endsWith('-->'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_comment = false;
                    }
                    else if(line.endsWith('/video>'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_video = false;
                    }
                    else if(line.endsWith('/style>'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_css_block = false;
                    }
                    else if(line.startsWith('<code'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_code_block = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.startsWith('<pre'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_pre_block = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.startsWith('<table'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_table = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.startsWith('<!--'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_comment = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.startsWith('<video'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_video = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.startsWith('<style'))
                    {
                            line_is_inside_css_block = true;
                    }
            }
    );
    var output = lines.join('\n');
    output = output.replace(/\n\n+/g,'\n\n');
    output = output.replace(/\<\/p\>\n\<br/g,'\n<br');
    output = output.replace(/\<i\>/g,'<em>');
    output = output.replace(/\<\/i\>/g,'</em>');
    return output;
}

$('button').click(
  function() {
var input_text = $('#input').val();
var output_text = Add_paragraph_tags(input_text);
$('#output').val(output_text);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="input">
This line should have paragraph tags.

<pre>This is code and does not need paragraph tags</pre>

<em>This line should have paragraph tags.</em>

<h1>This is a header and it does not need paragraph tags</h1>

<blockquote>This is a blockquote. This line needs a paragraph tag.

Paragraph tags are needed here too.</blockquote>

<ul>
<li>This is a list item. It does not need a paragraph tag</li>
</ul>

</textarea>

<textarea id="output"></textarea>

<button type="button">Add paragraph tags</button>
```

Comment: Thanks to Paul for this code. I tested it but it contains errors. For example what if the previous line ends with<br> or <br />? What about linebreaks inside a <p>, they should not get additional <p>? There are too many edge cases. I have to remove this from production.